# Why won't Windows boot from a new SSD?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, windows-8.1, ssd

I have an Windows 8.1 system with one volume. I want to upgrade the main drive to an SSD. I bought a Samsung 850 PRO. I physically installed it, then used the "Samsung Data Migration" utility that came with the new SSD to copy over the contents of the boot drive.

Then I disconnected the old drive. I checked the BIOS to make sure the new drive is detected. There it is...

[image]

However, when I try to log in, it just stays like this for about a really long time...

[image]

Then the screen goes blank.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: did you initialize the disk as a GPT type drive before you ran the Samsung tool?

Comment: No, I didn't know about GPT. None of the how-to articles I referenced mentioned MBR/GPT. I just let Samsung's bundled tools do their thing. I'll try again, initializing the disk first as GPT type. Thanks for the info.

Comment: many laptops fail to properly boot from MBR disks using EFI, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. the last 2 laptops I switched from HDD to SSD were GPT factory partition structure (WIn7 and 8.1) and cloned successfully to a GPT initialized disk. I don't know if the Samsung tool modifies the partition table, but other tools do not

Comment: This is actually a desktop machine, but I understand what you're saying. I'll try initializing the drive as GPT & re-doing the cloning operation. Thanks again!